# mysql structuring categories

Tags: mysql, structure, categories

I am not that experienced yet with MYSQL, so please make your answers as extensive as possible. Thanks.

For the sake of learning the mechanics and code, I decided to try and make a catalogue. A database will hold to product **id, title, (name), content, image path and thumbnail path**. The products should also be part of a *one or more* categories, so they can be filtered. Take I have about 7 **categories**.

Even after reading and searching and can't really decide which is the best option for structuring the lot.

- One table with many colums? With a column for each category and a 1 or 0 value in the rows?
- One table for the information and a table for the categories, also having 1 or 0 values, and linked with a parent from the first table. And joining them together.

I do not really have an idea what is best or easiest to structure, organize and use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should *never* go with any kind of solution that has a variable number of *columns* (i.e. your first solution).  There is no guarantee that a product will have up to 7 categories nor is there a guarantee that a product will have even one category.  You would end up having to `ALTER` this table frequently, and there is no simple way to select categories without specifying multiple columns.

The second solution is much better -- a table of `Categories` that has an identifier and the category name in each row.  Then you just need another table that has (Product Identifier, Category Identifier), and you can link products to as many or as few categories as you like.

```
CREATE TABLE Categories (
    catID int unsigned not null auto_increment primary key,
    catName varchar(255),
    unique key (catName)
);
CREATE TABLE ProductCategories (
    pcID int unsigned not null auto_increment primary key,
    proID int unsigned,
    catID int unsigned,
    unique key (proID, catID),
    foreign key (proID) references Products (id),
    foreign key (catID) references Categories (catID)
);
```

Comment: Great answer. Yet some questions:
1) first paragraph, how is the amount of colums variable? When a new category is added?
2) table Categories has rows of ex: id: 1, catName: example one ; id:2, catName: example two ; Correct?
3) SQL didn't accept your third query (error 150), so will be trying it myself, but how would it work exactly, where do i add the multiple categories a product is linked to?

Comment: @PépéArtist 1) because a product may have 1-inf. categories; you would have to grow/shrink the table columns.  2) Exactly

Comment: accidently posted the first comment to soon by pressing enter, editted it with a question 3, but you already answered. I am still not sure about question one. The possible categories are static and predefined. One could not choose to add a non-existing category to a product. Is your answer still the same in this case?

Comment: @PépéArtist all I'm saying is that there is no way for you to know that categories will be static and predefined forever.  At some point you're probably going to want to add a new category or remove an existing one.  May never come up, but if it does then you have a lot more work with solution #1 than with solution #2

Comment: Great, so I was following correctly. Thanks! Also found out where the error came from. I used a smallint(9) for the products id. Could you answer my last question in the the first comment? Oh, and the foreign key & references is the link across the tables, right?

Comment: @PépéArtist 150 is a foreign key error; make sure foreign keys are referencing key columns and you are using InnoDB tables.  These do link across tables.  `ProductCategories` has the ID of the product and all of the catIDs that correspond to categories for that product

Comment: so example: pcID: 1 ; proID: 1 ; catID: 1,2,4,7  ? Or each catID as a different row?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/33199/discussion-between-explosion-pills-and-pepe-artist)